# Music player for iTunes library

Tags: macos, itunes, music

I have a music collection composed of music from my CD's and iTunes purchased music. This collection is stored in iTunes. Is there a 3rd party music player that will play this collection? If so, how does one import the iTunes music into the 3rd party player.

Comment: What does the music player have to do differently to iTunes?

Comment: I don't know. I tried 4 music players but I couldn't get any of them to load songs from iTunes.

Comment: Sorry the question was what does iTunes do wrong?

Comment: Nothing. I just wanted to test drive a different music player.  iTunes is fine.

Comment: Most DJ Softwares (djay, Traktor) can access the iTunes library. It is very difficult to give you an actual answer as there isn't really a question apart from you wanting a list of all players that can access the iTunes library..

Comment: @KevinGrabher That's an answer as far as I'm concerned.  If you want to pose that as an answer I'll select it.  I tried apps like Vox and Clementine but no luck there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most music players, you have to go into the settings and there should be a setting where you point the app to the folder where your music is stored. the same as you do in itunes settings in the advanced tab. look for that. its got to be in the settings somewhere. you could also just try to open the music app, and drag the music folder into the player screen. also the same as itunes.

Comment: i'll try this. If it works I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks.